If field updates to give me a result SQL or POWER BI
I have a column of names if there is an update to that name i want it to tell me it has changed. there is no footprint to tell me it has changed so I'm having to work from the specific column / cell.



Name
updated?




Bob Harry
Y


Sandra Bu
N



Im unsure of any methods in SQL or power BI to do this

Check out triggers.
